# How can I amplify the microampere current of a piezoelectric sensor up to milli-ampere?

Tags: amplifier, piezoelectricity, renewable-energy

I want to harvest the energy from piezoelectric sensors to charge a 3.7V battery but the piezoelectric only produces a microampere current. Is it possible to to amplify it to charge the battery faster?

Comment: In very low energy situations, a more integrated solution can provide higher efficiency than building each module separately. There are ICs designed to harvest energy from piezo/thermocouple/etc sources and boost it to a more easily usable voltage. I suggest looking into those.

Comment: Power does not work that way. You need to either reduce the voltage when increasing current, or load match.

Comment: Parallel 1000 of them?

Answer (score 1):

With energy, it isn't possible to get a free lunch.

It's relatively easy to amplify a microampere *signal* up to milliamperes, but that's because the extra current comes from some type of power supply. This doesn't work when the signal you're trying to amplify *is* the power supply.

You might be able to use a transformer to trade current for voltage. If your piezoelectric sensor produces 1 microampere and 100 volts, you might be able to transform it to 100 microamperes and 1 volt, or 25 microamperes and 4 volts.

Current times voltage is power, and power over time is energy, and according to the known laws of physics, you can't get more energy out than you put in.

There's also a factor of time. If you have 100 microamperes 100% of the time, you can transform it to, 1 milliampere 10% of the time, or 10 milliamperes 1% of the time, by charging a capacitor or battery and then using it up when it gets to a certain level.